# Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I am Running Eclipse Kelper Build id: 20130614-0229 (the latest at time of writing)

I have installed the Web Tools Platform (WTP) and I am using a 'static web project'.

I keep getting an error alert box popping up with the error

```
Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants
```

Okay I have searched high and low for a solution, but of course the solution seems to be different for every version of eclipse. I went to a bug post on this at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389968

but the advice was just to "get the right version of EPP for your workspace"

Okay so that advice is no help at all. How does one know what is the right version of their workspace? what do they mean by that anyway? by "for your workspace" are they referring to your version of Eclipse? or is that a separate issue?

I saw another response to this issue on stack overflow for Eclipse Juno, but it was simply a link to a temporary patch update site which no longer exists. Someone else on that thread claimed that Kelper had a fix for all of this. Clearly that is not the case and the people at Eclipse.org do not think this is a bug.

Comment: I have added it as a bug again in the eclipse bugzilla.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413954

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From update site, install below item:
|> Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development
    * Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools

Answer (score 5):

I would guess that you are seeing this issue because you have not installed enough of WTP. That doesn't make this problem less of an issue, but at least you can look for workarounds in how you construct your installation. The easiest solution is to grab the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" package.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the *JST Enterprise Core* feature, `org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_core.feature`